# Emulating a trail effect

Tags: unity, vfxgraph

I'm trying to emulate a VFX Graph trail effect I have found, however I'm having an issue with achieving a similar effect. The reference I'm using seems to use some randomness for lifetime and for color, I'm not quite sure but it looks like it's sampling colors from a gradient, but also picks nearby colors in the gradient. The gradient seems to go from red (low opacity) to intense greens and blues (mixing) then to darker blues (low opacity) woth large gaps and single particles near the end of its lifetime. I'd appreciate some tips to make my effect more accurately represent the referece.

Specifically I'm looking at the floor trails either side of the projectile (but not the transparent particle strips).

**What I've achieved so far:** https://streamable.com/ub4ba9

**My VFX Graph:**

[image]

**What I'd like to achieve:** https://streamable.com/yvw6f4

Any advice is apprecaited.

(I'd upload the animated gifs to imgur but they are too large to upload, I'm not able to cut the size to 2MB without reducing the visibility of the whole effect.)